# Jssor - using images as captions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a Jssor slideshow, but I'm having trouble doing something, and it's certainly due to my lack of javascripting knowledge.

I'd like to include captions with the images, but I need to use specific fonts that aren't standard.  To do this, I'd like to include images that contain the text I need.  I tried altering one of the captioned examples, but it just hangs when it gets to my graphic caption.

I altered the second slide image code, replacing the caption text with an  tag:

http://test10.ssih.com/Jssor/examples-jquery/slider-with-caption.source.html

Is there a "correct" way for me to do this?

Per request, some code.  I'm not sure how much would be meaningful, but here is the section I edited:

```
<!-- Slide -->
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/landscape/02.jpg" />
                <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" t2="T" style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0px;
                    width: 600px; height: 50px;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 50px;
                        background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 50px;
                        color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                        <img src="../../slideshow/co2.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As far as the problem description goes, I don't know how much more descriptive I can be without simply repeating myself.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following image caption definition make sense?

```
<img u="caption" t="L" src="url" style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 50px;" />
```

Comment: Yes it does, and I've found that on a couple of your examples, so I can get what I need from them.  Thanks!